# Kubernetes: Unable to create repository

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I'm following [Kubernete's getting started guide](http://kubernetes.io/docs/hellonode/). Everything went smoothly until I ran

`$ gcloud docker push gcr.io/<PROJECT ID>/hello-node:v1`

(Where  is, well, my project id). For some reason, Kubernetes is not able to push to the registry. This is what I get:

```
Warning: '--email' is deprecated, it will be removed soon. See usage.
Login Succeeded
Warning: '--email' is deprecated, it will be removed soon. See usage.
Login Succeeded
Warning: '--email' is deprecated, it will be removed soon. See usage.
Login Succeeded
Warning: '--email' is deprecated, it will be removed soon. See usage.
Login Succeeded
Warning: '--email' is deprecated, it will be removed soon. See usage.
Login Succeeded
Warning: '--email' is deprecated, it will be removed soon. See usage.
Login Succeeded
Warning: '--email' is deprecated, it will be removed soon. See usage.
Login Succeeded
The push refers to a repository [gcr.io/kubernetes-poc-1320/hello-node]
18465c0e312f: Preparing 
5f70bf18a086: Preparing 
9f7afc4ce40e: Preparing 
828b3885b7b1: Preparing 
5dce5ebb917f: Preparing 
8befcf623ce4: Waiting 
3d5a262d6929: Waiting 
6eb35183d3b8: Waiting 
denied: Unable to create the repository, please check that you have access to do so.
```

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong? Note that I have run. `$ gcloud init`, so I've logged in.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but your answer below did not help :[

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: This worked for me months ago. New versions of Kubernetes might not have this problem, or this solution might not solve it :)

Ok, after struggling for hours with this, I finally managed to push it to th grc.io registry by changing my tag from a `image:version` notation to `image/version`, like this:

`gcloud docker push gcr.io/<PROJECT ID>/hello-node/v1`

after reading another guide from Kubernetes' documentation: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing#pushing_to_the_registry

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't recommend doing this because it's just going to create folders v1, v2, ... v{n} and every container will have the actual version of latest. I checked the docs and don't understand why they recommended this though.  My issue came down to creating the kubernetes cluster via Google's UI, and the VMs created didn't have write access to the GCR bucket.  I then provisioned a cluster using CLI and didn't have any issues.  An example command: `gcloud container clusters create my-special-cluster \
  --num-nodes 3 \
  --scopes "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/projecthosting,storage-rw"`

Comment: On mentioned page I do not see this version usage hint. Neither __:v1__ and __/v1__ works for me :-(
__docker login__ runs successful.

Answer (score 8):

This solved it in my case:

---

**Short version:**

Press `Enable billing` in the `Container Engine` screen in the `https://console.cloud.google.com`.

---

**Long version:**

In my case I got the error because of an issue with setting billing in the google cloud platform console.

Although I entered all my credit card information and the screen of my `Container Engine` Screen in the google cloud platform console said `Container Engine is getting ready. This may take a minute or more.`, it didn't work before I pressed `Enable billing` on the same screen. Then the `gcloud docker push` command finally worked.

Oddly enough after later returning to the `Container Engine` screen, it shows me `Container Engine is getting ready. This may take a minute or more.` and the button `Enable billing` again.. must be a bug in the console.

Comment: I do not see __Enable billing__ on the __Container Engine__ screen. Checking __gcloud container clusters get-credentials__ gives error __ResponseError: code=403, message=Required "container.clusters.get" permission for "projects/***__

Comment: I had to go to the project's dashboard, click on the box that said 'Resources' where it says "Cloud Storage" in that cluster of boxes in the middle of the dashboard page and *then* I saw the Enable Billing button. Once I clicked it everything worked. This is the worst UI. It should be like a big red notice when you're on that project that billing hasn't been enabled yet.

Comment: @BjornTipling It could be that the UI changed since my answer (it's half a year old) but unfortunately not for the better.. If you confirm that that's the current official UI, I can refer to it in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

None of the above solutions worked for me and I finally found out a solution. I'm using Windows 10 and looked at my C:/Users//.docker/config.json file and it looked like this.

```
{
    "auths": {
        "https://appengine.gcr.io": {},
        "https://asia.gcr.io": {},
        "https://b.gcr.io": {},
        "https://bucket.gcr.io": {},
        "https://eu.gcr.io": {},
        "https://gcr.io": {},
        "https://gcr.kubernetes.io": {},
        "https://us.gcr.io": {}
    },
    "credsStore": "wincred"
}
```

Removing the **"credsStore": "wincred"** line fixed the problem!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a GCE instance, you need to make sure it has the right Cloud API access scope.
Since you can't edit the scopes on running instances, you can create a new instance using your current disk.

To do that, do the following

- Go to your instance page and click **Edit**
- Uncheck **Delete boot disk when instance is deleted** and click **save**
- Create a new instance using your previous disk and with write permissions on Storage.

Comment: This was the issue I encountered. Note that you may now add permissions to existing instances without having to recreate them (only switch them off).

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this same error because I was accidentally using the project *name* rather than the auto-generated *id*.  The `PROJECT_ID` can be found via:

```
$ gcloud info
```

as well as in the Google Cloud dashboard: https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard

Silly, I realize, but I can imagine others making the same mistake :)

Comment: Many, many thanks. I definitely assumed that I was on the right project. Step 1: is your computer on? ...

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you are authenticated with Google Cloud.

```
$ gcloud auth application-default login
```

Double-check `gcloud` is pointing to your current project.

```
$ gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID
```

If you still have trouble, run `gcloud info` and take a look at the `Last Log File`. Note: `gcloud auth login` no longer writes application default credentials.

Comment: This fixed my problem, by I can't understand why I was able to push an image and than, after a few hours, I got the error and had to re-run `gcloud auth` to get it working again.

Answer (score 1):

In https://stackoverflow.com/a/39996807/598513 I answered switching user/account

```
gcloud auth list
gcloud config set account example@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, having the same error, I found I missed the "gcloud" in the beginning. That was because previous 2 commands started with docker and I just glanced over the changes after docker.

```
~/gs-spring-boot/complete$ docker -- push gcr.io/kubernetes-codelab-1xxxxx/hello-java:v1
```

correct:

```
~/gs-spring-boot/complete$ gcloud docker -- push gcr.io/kubernetes-codelab-1xxxxx/hello-java:v1
```

Answer (score 0):

run `gcloud init` and see whether you have logged in to the correct account. I once had this error because of i was trying to push image from different google account

Answer (score 0):

When using [docker-credential-helpers](https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers) to store docker credentials in the OSX Keychain, `gcloud docker -- push $registry/$project_id/<image>:<tag>` fails as well.

Solution for me was to revert `~/.docker/config.json` to not store credentials securely with the keychain

See also: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-common/issues/198

Answer (score -1):

What do you use as a project id? It shouldn't be "my-kubernetes-codelab", it should be "my-kubernetes-codelab-234231" or whatever your numbered version is. This was my problem.